# using CallMsg Data field

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

In the go-ethereum codebase, there's a type called [CallMsg](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#CallMsg) that's used in a number of cases, and the documentation says

> // input data, usually an ABI-encoded contract method invocation

and it takes a byte array. As far as I can tell, if you want to interact with contracts programmatically with Go, using this type is usually involved. Given a Solidity contract, how would I use this to invoke a method on that Solidity contract?

Comment: Well I can't answer my own question yet but I've determined that this field should be compiled bytecode. I haven't figured out how to use it specifically yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the bytecode you need, given a Solidity contract, would be to use `solc` with the `--bin` option on your contract. Then it will output the bytecode you need. Additionally, `abigen` can handle this for you by using the `--sol` flag to generate Java or Go code that uses this bytecode.